# How to run OPTIMIZE TABLE with the least downtime

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a MySQL 5.5 DB of +-40GB on a 64GB RAM machine in a production environment. All tables are InnoDB. There is also a slave running as a backup.

One table - the most important one - grew to 150M rows, inserting and deleting became slow. To speed up inserting and deleting I deleted half of the table. This did not speed up as expected; inserting and deleting is still slow.

I've read that running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` can help in such a scenario. As I understand this operation will require a read lock on the entire table and optimizing the table might take quite a while on a big table.

What would be a good strategy to optimize this table while minimizing downtime?

**EDIT** The specific table to be optimized has +- 91M rows and looks like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| channel_key | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| track_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| posted_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dead        | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "slowing down"?  These operations should still be pretty efficient (under most circumstances) even on large tables.  Also, edit the question to show the definition of the table.

Comment: -1 "OPTIMIZE strategy" is not a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the table definition. By slowing down I mean that a single insert went from around 20 ms to around 300 ms, that is still the same, also after deleting a lot of rows.

Comment: OPTIMIZE TABLE will completly recreate your table. It's defintly worth it after deleting a lot of rows, but unfortunatly there is not much you can do to speed it up.
You could reduce the the disk access to speed it up or use an ssd.
Also you should make sure you have enough space on your disk, since it's copying the entire table in a temp. table.

Comment: Is this an Innodb table? Are you using innodb_file_per_table? What's the host memory usage like? Size of innodb_buffer_pool_size if table is InnoDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Percona Toolkit's [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) does this for you. In this case it worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

300 ms to insert seems excessive, even with slow disks. I would look into the root cause. Optimizing this table is going to take a lot of time. MySQL will create a copy of your table on disk.

Depending on the size of your innodb_buffer_pool (if the table is innodb), free memory on the host, I would try to preload the whole table in the page cache of the OS, so that at least reading the data will be sped up by a couple orders of magnitude.

If you're using innodb_file_per_table, or if it's a MyISAM table, it's easy enough to make sure the whole file is cached using "time cat /path/to/mysql/data/db/huge_table.ibd > /dev/null". When you rerun the command, and it runs in under a few seconds, you can assume the file content is sitting in the OS page cache.

You can monitor the progress whilst the "optimize table" is running, by looking at the size of the temporary file. It's usually in the database data directory, with a temp filename starting with a dash (#) character.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/12/09/mysql-optimize-tables-innodb-stop/) suggests to first drop all indexes in a table, then optimize it, and then add indexes back. It claims the speed difference is 20 times compared to just optimize.

Answer (score 0):

update your version of mysql, in 8.0.x version the optimize table is fastest than 5.5
a optimize in a table with 91 millions could take like 3 hours in your version, you can run in morning, like 3am to not disturb the users of your app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).